# cameras.isEmpty null Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, camera, flutter

Anyone can tell my fault, when I use example [for camera Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/example/lib/main.dart) the error was

> NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
> Receiver : null
> Tried calling: isEmpty

I've implemented the permission for android and ios

Comment: Are you using minSdkVersion 21

Comment: yes I use minSdkVersion 21 in build.gradle android

Comment: Are you using <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> permission in manifest. Not sure for flutter but when you read camera info or use camera, you need this permission.

Comment: still doesn't work huhu. I don't know why it's happen :(

Comment: Just wanted to confirm if you already enabled the Camera permission

Comment: it's only working when I put the code on main.dart, thanks @PankajKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use library **image_picker: ^0.4.12** and I implement

```
_getImage(context, ImageSource.camera
```

onTap and this is the magical code

```
void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source){
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 400.0).then((File image){
  setState(() {
    _imageFile = image;
  });
  Navigator.pop(context);
});
}
```

voila!

[image]
[image]
[image]

thanks udemy :)